# When the codes in python file run when it's being imported?

Tags: python

I have two files, say `main.py` and `foo.py`. When I import `foo` in `main`, I thought the lines in `foo.py` that not in a function automaticly run.

But when I add an executable to `PATH` in `foo`, and call main of `foo` that involves that executable which should be in `PATH`, it gives an error: *geckodriver executable must be in PATH*. If I add it to `PATH` right after the imports in `main.py`, it works correctly.  Here are the sample codes:

**main.py**:

```py
# some imports
from foo_file import foo

foo.main()
```

**foo.py**:

```py
import os

FILENAME = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.join(FILENAME, "assets")

def main():
    # some work involves selenium
```

Why the first try doesn't work and gives the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a wild guess, but since you are importing `foo` as

```
from foo_file import foo
```

I assume that `foo` is in a sub-directory, i.e. something like

```
+- main.py
\- foo_file
   \- foo.py
```

Thus, when you add `os.path.abspath(__file__)` to PATH, it will add the path of the subdirectory, not of the directory containing the `main.py`, which is probably the directory that contains the `assets` folder, since you said that it works fine if the PATH-adding code is directly in `main`.

You can easily check (a) that and when the code is executed, and (b) which path is retrieved, if you add an accordant `print` line in both the `foo.py` and `main.py` files, e.g.

```
print(__file__, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: Aw yess, you absolutely correct, how I didn't see that. Thanks, I will try it asap.

Comment: Do you know how can I get the path of assets from foo in a good way?